# Debug IOS Application on the AMD notebook

Tags: ios, visual-studio, xamarin, visual-studio-debugging, amd-processor

I have notebook with the AMD FX 7500 processor and Windows 10 pro.
I also have installed VS 2015 Community and Xamarin. Is it possible to debug developed iOS application without iPhone? If yes, then how?

Comment: You have read [this](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/deployment,_testing,_and_metrics/debugging_in_xamarin_ios/) Also, reading [this](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/getting_started/installation/windows/) you do need a mac system to do this.

Comment: You'll need a Mac. End of story. Xamarin is working to bring the iOS simulator and USB debugging to Windows when CONNECTED to a Mac, though. You can use a cloud hosted pay-as-you-go Mac service, such as http://www.macincloud.com.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  You have to have an OSX machine to act as a build host.

Comment: Can I install Mac OSX on virtual box and work with virtual machine ?

Comment: The OS X license explicitly forbids doing this.  You may be able to get it to work technically, but I haven't tried.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot build, run or test an iOS app without a Mac.

You may install Mac OS on VM on a PC but it's illegal (Apple does not allow this in the Mac OS TOS) and it often does not really work.

As [Xamarin doc says](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/getting_started/installation/windows/introduction_to_xamarin_ios_for_visual_studio/):

> There are a few requirements that must be adhered to when developing
>   for iOS in Visual Studio. As briefly mentioned in the overview, a Mac
>   is required to compile IPA files, and applications cannot be deployed
>   to a device without Apple’s certificates and code-signing tools. Also,
>   the iOS simulator can be used only on a Mac.

Comment: Can xamarin cloud test help me?

Comment: Xamarin test cloud allows you to run UI tests on physical devices. It is not a sufficient tool for the development of apps. AND it requires uploading the built app, which you cannot create with a Mac. So Test Cloud won't help you at all.